# how can I display below q-options-group the description of an object of array?

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework

i have this array

```
const options = [
  {
    label: 'Monday',
    value: 'Monday',
    description:'dsdfsdfsdfdsfds'
  },
  {
    label: 'Tuesday',
    value: 'Tuesday',
    description:'dsdfsdfsdfdsfds'
  },
  {
    label: 'Wednesday',
    value: 'Wednesday',
    description:'dsdfsdfsdfdsfds'
  },
  {
    label: 'Thursday',
    value: 'Thursday',
    description:'dsdfsdfsdfdsfds'
  },
  {
    label: 'Friday',
    value: 'Friday',
    description:'dsdfsdfsdfdsfds'
  },
  {
    label: 'Saturday',
    value: 'Saturday',
    description:'dsdfsdfsdfdsfds'
  },
  {
    label: 'Sunday',
    value: 'Sunday',
    description:'dsdfsdfsdfdsfds'
  }
];
```

and this is the `q-option-group`

```
  <q-option-group
      v-model="group"
      :options="options"
      color="green"
      type="checkbox"
    />
```

and this is the display in front end
[image]

I'm wondering if it is possible to add text below each checkbox or display the description from the object of an array? how can I achieve that?

Comment: `q-option-group` is meant to simplify the usage of checkbox groups for common use cases and lacks advanced customization.  If the use of [label slots](https://quasar.dev/vue-components/option-group#using-label-slots) is not adequate for your needs you can always use `v-for` with `q-checkbox` and design a group of checkboxes however you want